# how to add permalink/slug to wordpress custom link menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, slug

In WordPress `wp-admin` navigate to  :

- Appearance > Menus > Add menu items > Custom Links
- in Custom Links we can add a `CSS ID` in the `URL` field, example :

> [image]

- in another page, i have html tag provided by `elementor` that has a CSS id of `nuts-and-seeds`, example :

> [image]

- when the user clicks on the menu item it scrolls to the desierd element, which is fine.

is there a way to add a **permalink/slug** to the menu item?

- when user clicks on the menu item the expected url should be :
  `www.example.com/nuts-and-seeds`
- now the url looks like : `www.example.com/`

thanks

Comment: add `www.example.com/nuts-and-seeds` in the URL field

Comment: Hi Temani, but `/nuts-and-seeds` is not any post or page, it is a CSS id property `#nuts-and-seeds`. I want to push the menu item title for example `Nuts and Seeds`  as a slug/permalink `/nuts-and-seeds` when the user clicks on the item. cheers :D

Comment: that doesn't make a lot of sense unless you are building a one page App with a complex JS to handle slugs. In all the cases, what you need cannot be done in that section or anywhere in wordpress. You may need to search for a plugin that update slug dynamically

Comment: thanks for explaining @TemaniAfif it is indeed one page App. Is there any recommendation for a plugin or a tweak to deal with that ? I have updated my question so it makes more sence